# Switching views without initialization in iOS

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

There are two views in my application.

After launching the app I switch the view with button like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController *view = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view_a"];

[self presentViewController:view_a animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But whenever i switch the view the code above initialize the view. 
I want to maintain previous status of the view.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` always returns a new instance of an `UIViewController`.

You need to keep a reference to a previous one if you don't want to create it over and over.

Answer (score 0):

On an iPad this will present the second view modally, as dictated by the views modalTransitionStyle.  So there you could get back to the original by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on the new ViewController.

On the iPhone you can use a UINavigationController in your storyboard to push and then pop the secondViewController.

As long as you are using the storyboard, you can set up the transition there and the perform it using - `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` from your button.  Or for that matter you can connect the segue directly to your button in which case the transition will be performed without additional code.